# How can I connect my Kubernetes pod to a remote Jaeger?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jaeger, open-telemetry

I am trying to connect my pod from Kubernetes (k8s) cluster to a remote Jaeger server. I've tested and it can work well if both of them are on the same machine. However, when I run my app on k8s, my app can not connect to Jaeger despite I were using physical IP.
First, I've tried this:

```
containers:
 - name: api
   env:
    - name: OTEL__AGENT_HOST
      value: <my-physical-ip>
    - name: OTEL__AGENT_PORT
      value: "6831"
```

After read the docs from the internet, I add the Jaeger agent to my deployments as a sidecar container like this.

```
containers:
        - name: api
          env:
            - name: OTEL__AGENT_HOST
              value: "localhost"
            - name: OTEL__AGENT_PORT
              value: "6831"
        - image: jaegertracing/jaeger-agent
          name: jaeger-agent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5775
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 6831
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 6832
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 5778
            protocol: TCP
          args: ["--reporter.grpc.host-port=<my-physical-ip>:14250"]
```

It seems work very well on both containers. But on the collector of Jaeger, I received a log like this:

```
{"level":"warn","ts":1641987200.2678068,"caller":"channelz/logging.go:62","msg":"[core]grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = \"transport: http2Server.
HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: read tcp 172.20.0.4:14250-><the-ip-of-machine-my-pods-are-deployed>:32852: i/o timeout\"","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I exposed port 14267 on Jaeger collector on remote machine, then change  `args: ["--reporter.grpc.host-port=<my-physical-ip>:14250"]` to `args: ["--reporter.grpc.host-port=<my-physical-ip>:14267"]` and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using jaeger operator? https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator

This is how you will install it :

```
kubectl create namespace observability 
kubectl create -f https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/releases/download/v1.31.0/jaeger-operator.yaml -n observability
```

then you can create Jaeger instance that will up jaeger components like collector, agent, query . You can define storage too .. like elastic search for e.g.

```
apiVersion: jaegertracing.io/v1
kind: Jaeger
metadata:
  name: simple-prod-es
spec:
  strategy: production
  storage:
    type: elasticsearch 
    options:
      es:
        server-urls: https://search-test-g7fbo7pzghdquvvgxty2pc6lqu.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com
        index-prefix: jaeger-span
        username: test
        password: xxxeee
```

Then in your application's deployment yaml file you will need to configure agent as a side car (or u can use agent as deamonset) so that request can be forwarded to the collector ..

More details here: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.31/operator/#deployment-strategies

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: let me edit answer